# How to run a html file on localhost (any port)

Tags: html, macos, localhost

I am creating a website using HTML, CSS and js with java for server side. I need to run it on localhost. I am using MacOS X 11 (el Capitan).

I have already tried python and node.js but it clashes with Java, so I need a technology that won't clash with Java and will help me localhost on Mac.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IIRC macOS comes with PHP preinstalled, and PHP has built-in web-server which should be enough for serving static content.

So, open Terminal.app and then:

```sh
cd your/project/dir
php -S localhost:8080
```

After than you can navigate to http://localhost:8080/ and see your site in the browser (given you have `index.html` in your project, otherwise there will be "Not Found" message).

There are more advanced and/or less terminal-oriented ways, of course, but since you already tinkering with python and node, another terminal command should not be a problem.

BTW, you might want to look at that terminal window from time to time, as it outputs nice log of what things were requested from server. Good if you want to check for invalid references, 404 errors, etc. Here is a sample output:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
PHP 7.3.6 Development Server started at Sat Jun 22 20:00:28 2019
Listening on http://localhost:8080
Document root is /private/tmp/test
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Sat Jun 22 20:00:32 2019] [::1]:51640 [200]: /
[Sat Jun 22 20:00:32 2019] [::1]:51641 [200]: /style.css
[Sat Jun 22 20:02:35 2019] [::1]:51670 [404]: /oops.html - No such file or directory
```

As you can see, root folder (`/`, which was translated to `index.html` in my case) and a stylesheet (`style.css`) were requested and successfully delivered (code is `200`). But non-existent file `oops.html` resulted in error (code is `404`).

Comment: Thanks a lot but won't it clash with java?

Comment: The only way I see it could clash is port number. If your Java application(s) happen to use port 8080, just come with any other number in range 1025...65535. Then use that number in both php command and browser URL.

Comment: No i mean can i use 2 backend languages together

Comment: Oh, you know what, I just realized you have java backend, and now I don't understand why you need python, node, or php to serve your site -- you already have java. Can you be more specific what you mean by "clash"? Is there any specific error message when you try it with python or node?

Comment: So you mean i should use java to use localhost?

Comment: Well, I have no idea how your java backend is done and what it wants as configuration. Can't give you any advice without knowing specifics of your case.

Comment: I am sorry i have not yet started java. Also i develop only frontend, my friend develops backend

Comment: "Backend" is a broad term, it could mean Java will serve static pages too, or it could mean Java provides only some REST API, and there needs to be other thingie (like Apache, nginx, etc.) that will serve your HTML/CSS/JS. Yet again, I don't know which scenario is yours, so, I can't help.

Comment: So i use HTML CSS and js. My friend will use java to connect to db

Comment: As in what, i think i have given enough info. What more info do you need?

Comment: You did not explain your problem. "Clashes" -- does it mean error message? What does that message say?

Comment: As i said i havn't started java so i don't know.

Comment: Nope, you said literally "I have already tried python and node.js but it clashes with java" -- not "will clash" or "I think it will clash", but "it clashes". Anyhow, why do you expect problems? Why not resolve the problem when (if) it occurs?

Comment: I regret for my mistakes. But my friend told me about this

Comment: Then best course wouid be to ask your friend what is he talking about. I conclude this topic is closed, goodbye.

Comment: PHP isn't enabled or installed anymore on Mac: `zsh: command not found: php`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy)

Install: `brew install caddy`

To serve static files from the current working directory, run:

```
caddy file-server --browse --listen :2015
```

Caddy's default port is 2015, so open your browser to http://localhost:2015.

Comment: That does not seem to be true anymore with the current version. I needed to use `caddy file-server --browse --listen :2015`. Just running `caddy` shows the help text now.